# Dynamically create multiple DataTables based on number of records returned from SQL query in C#?

Tags: c#

I am querying a database to get a dynamically number of records, let's say I get 11000 records returned.

Currently I am inserting every record in one DataTable. I loop through each records in the table and query a web service to get more data related to this record (which I save in  a Response object).

It was working fine till I didn't have more than 1000 records but apparently there's a limit on the web service that I can only query for 1000 records at a time.

I wonder how I can dynamically create 11 datatables if I have 11000 records, 12 datatables if I have 11001 records and so on. Then for each datatable I query the web service and bind the response to Response object as usual. Is this possible or is there a much better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work.

```
DataTable dt = LoadDataTable()
List<DataTable> splitTables = new List<DataTable>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i+=1000 )
{
    splitTables.Add(dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(i).Take(1000).CopyToDataTable());
}
```